# Embed environment variable in executable which is build from configure script

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, environment-variables, configure

Can I embed some environment variable in executable using configure script so that when that executable is launched, some particular environment variable is automatically set.

For example:
When we launch `python3` executable, `PYTHONPATH` automatically gets set. Or on launching `xyz.exe`, `XYZ` variable gets set.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no. You generally cannot directly modify a binary executable, or set environment variables depending on the specific executable being run. And many tools and programs have comprehensive command line options to allow you to specify how it should run, so make sure you read the documentation closely to make sure there is no pre-defined way to do what you want. That being said you could replicate this functionality with a few workarounds.

One solution would be to explicitly `export` all the environment variables, so that they are always defined when you run the executable. This will of course lead to a lot of environment variables be set with no guarantee they will be used.

You could also write an alias or function so that you set the environment variable before running the executable, if you want to minimize the amount of environment variables which are set at any given time. Be careful to use a name that won't clash with existing executables on the `PATH`. This solution is closer to what you question is looking for, since the environment variables are only present just before and after execution.

```
python3env() {
    export PYTHONPATH=/some/path
    python3
    unsert YOOT
}

alias python3env="export PYTHONPATH /some/path;python3;unset YOOT"
```

Of course both of theses examples will clutter your shell startup configurations, and may result in a lot of environment variables be set with no guarantee they will be used.

Comment: Thanks, it can be hacked around in many ways. I was looking for a more cleaner solution, something similar to passing `LDGLAGS` to configure script.

Comment: Ah, then not really. Unless you were looking to re-compile every binary and install it, there's no "good" way other than using the tool specific config files if they exist.

Comment: Idea was to compile a binary and ship it across distros without any installation dependencies.